# jquery plugin to notify users of a promotion

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a good popup, or slide down, or whatever to notify users of a promotion (think store). I saw something like that once, but i cant find the link any more.

I am looking for something "sexy", so it will attract the user's attention, but *not get in the way of things*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [jQuery Growl plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Growl).  It is not modal, but does display a notification.

Here's the [demo page](http://projects.zoulcreations.com/jquery/growl/)

I have used the [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)'s growl implementation as well.

Answer (score 2):

[jGrowl](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl) is amazing. I use it to notify users of recent changes to specific pages within my site.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with slide?  You can style however you'd like.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#show").click(function() {
            $("#slide").slideToggle();
        }
        )
    }
); 
</script>

<style>
#slide
{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: Red;
    color: White;
    display: none;
    top:0px;
}
</style>
<div id="slide" style="">
    Super Sexy promotion!
</div>
<a id="show" href="#">toggle</a>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen websites that use the [Page Peel](http://www.smartredfox.com/2008/12/corner-page-peel-advert-with-jquery/) effect to advertise promos.

I think it is quite catchy and works well to draw the user's eye to it. Here's a [demo](http://www.smartredfox.com/test/index.htm).